# AC and DC voltage are constant even though the frequency changes

Tags: ac, dc, frequency, oscilloscope, function-generator

In the circuit below, why does the AC voltage remain constant even though the frequency increases?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Can you say more about what situation you are asking about? There's no general rule that "the ac voltage stays constant as the frequency changes". Talking about the DC voltage changing as frequency doesn't make sense, because the dc voltage is the voltage at f = 0 Hz.

Comment: I connected a my circuit to a function generator and oscilloscope. My circuit is also connected to two resistors.I collected my AC voltage as I increase my frequency.However, I noticed that my Ac voltage did not actually change. When I reached, a frequency of 1 million, my AC voltage increased largely.

Comment: What is your circuit? You can upload an image file showing the schematic to an image hosting site, and let us know the link;  someone will edit your question to include it inline.

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/40ukyunch/Capture.jpg

Comment: @eLg  When you generate an AC waveform with a function generator and increase the frequency, the amplitude doesn't change.  This is how function generators usually work by design.

Comment: The voltage source is changed into a function generator and I used a DMM to measure the AC voltage

Comment: @NickAlexeev, I noticed that, is that the reason why the AC will not change?sorry I just started learning circuits, so I have no idea why would things do the way they do it.

Comment: @eLg  Instead of saying "AC will not change", you should be more specific.  Amplitude of AC doesn't change or frequency of AC doesn't change?  Best of all, post screenshot from the oscilloscope: figure 1, then increase frequency and post figure 2.  We'll be able to see what you see.

Comment: @eLg  Another thing.  This message board has a built-in tool for drawing schematics.  It's called CircuitLab.  It has a symbol for AC voltage source.  Press Control+M and you'll be able to draw schematics.

Comment: Voltage of AC obtained from a multimeter when frequency is changed using a function generator. @NickAlexeev, I am sorry, but I am not able to show any oscilloscope screenshot because I was not able to obtain them when I was conducting the experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see your circuit since the server in my university blocks the domain of the image hosting site, but based from your comment *"I connected a my circuit to a function generator and oscilloscope. My circuit is also connected to two resistors,"* I am assuming that those are the only components in your circuit so I will base my answer on that.

Resistor is a component that is **NOT** frequency dependent unlike capacitor \$X_{c} = \frac1{2pifC}\$ and inductor \$X_{L} = 2pifL\$. Following Ohm's law, \$V = IR\$, the voltage of the resistor will not change since \$X_{R} = R\$, in contrast with capacitor and inductor whose voltages will change over frequencies.

But if your circuit is RLC, RL, or RC, the total voltage should change in varying frequencies.

Comment: I can now see the circuit in your question. I therefore stand by my answer. Since resistors are not frequency dependent, even though you vary the frequency of your AC source, voltage reading at any two points in the circuit will not change due to frequency.